# Changing style class attributes dynamically in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have the following code in Angular 6:

```
<div [innerHtml]="content"></div>
```

I get the `content` variable from a service call (i.e. an external library). It contains class names, such as `p1`:

```
var content = '<p class="p1">This is some text</p>';
```

Now, I'm migrating this code from AngularJS. In AngularJS, I used to manipulate css classes like `p1` in the directive template:

```
.p1 {
   font-family: {{theFamily}};
}
```

But when I try to do the same in the Angular 6 component style sheet, I get `Module build failed: Syntax Error`.

Any ideas how to obtain the same result?

**UPDATE**
Please see this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html-djlm3k), it does not work because it doesn't accept `{{ }}` in the css. This worked in AngularJS.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use angular binding in Component scss. It should be used only in templates. You can use [ngStyle] which will call component function and return css properties as object.

**Template:**

```
<div [ngStyle]="getStyles()">This is test</div>

getStyles(){
    let styles = {
    'background-color': this.isExpired ? 'red' : 'transparent',
    'font-weight': this.isImportant ? 'bold' : 'normal'
  };
  return styles;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer my question because you are altering the HTML markup and not using classes. I need to keep the HTML as is and change the class externally.